# Convert vector of integers to string using nlohman json

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I am trying to convert an `std::vector` of integers. For this task I am using [nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library. What I am expecting to get is the string `"[3,5,18,11]"`, but I am receiving `"[[3,5,18,11]]"` as a result. I do not understand why I am getting another array wrapped and how to avoid it? Will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"

using namespace nlohmann;

int main() {
    const std::vector<uint64_t> data = { 3, 5, 18, 11 };

    json j = json{ data };
    auto result = j.dump();
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `json j = data;`?

Comment: Thanks, but why it is an array instead of object and curly braces?

Comment: json has `std::initializer_list` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just enough:

```cpp
const std::vector<uint64_t> data = { 3, 5, 18, 11 };
json j = data;
```

Comment: Isn't https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/array/ much easier, i.e. `auto j = json::array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`. The `vector` seems to be redundant here...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the OP presents an `std::vector`. It could have come from anywhere.